# How to change App icon on the Play Market's page

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-console-developer

I have a problem with Google Play. I can't change the app logo which showed in the Play Market's page of my app.

What did I do:

1) I changed the icon in the Google Play console (high definition icon 512x512);

2) I removed old instances of an old icon from /res directory;

3) I created new instances of the new icon in the /res directory (the launcher icon had changed on the device);

4) I uploaded the app to the Play Market.

Result: Launcher icon has changed on the device (and there no question to icons on devices), however, the app's page of Play Market shows the old app's icon.

Maybe important notes:

AndroindManifest.xml:

```
<application android:name=".AnalyticsApplication"
                 android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
-----
<activity android:name=".Activities.SplashScreenActivity_"
                  android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                  android:theme="@style/SplashScreenTheme"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
------
```

(I use Splash Screen without "android:icon").

Question: How to change App icon on the Play Market's page?

UPD. WHAT HAPPENED WITH ME (SOLUTION): 
My app is localized for three languages and High-res icon should be uploaded for every language (because the description icon was localized for 3 languages). Thank you for your time)

Comment: First, make sure that you actually pressed the "submit update" button on the store listing page in the google play console (I always forget). Then, give it half an hour or so - sometimes they take a while to update.

Comment: make sure there is no other logo in all mipmap folder with name `ic_launcher` then your desire one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The icon in the Play store is entirely determined by the Play console entry, not by the APK. So everything to do with the manifest is irrelevant. You say you have updated the 512x512 high-res icon in the Play console. If this is true then your icon should have updated. Things which may have got in the way:

- did you definitely republish your app
- did you definitely wait long enough for your new app to reach all of Google's servers
- did you definitely look at the store listing on a device which hadn't cached the old listing? The Play store app uses a local cache of app listings to prevent the same information being downloaded over and over again. Have you tried clearing the cache for the Play store? You do this by

  - On your phone (not Play store) Settings >
  - Apps
  - Google Play Store
  - Storage
  - Clear cache
- you can also check it by looking at the Play store on the web (but make sure browser cache is cleared)
- make sure you don't have any app store listing experiments running with the old icon
- remember the icon can be Localized, like the screenshots and text. If you update the icon, you'll need to do it in every language.

Comment: I have check every your point and I did everything. However, your tips could be very helpful for others). I updated the question with info about what happened.

Comment: Thanks for updating your question. I updated my answer to include the actual problem to hopefully be helpful to others

Answer (score 4):

You have to change it from play store panel .
This is app icon on android you have changed ( which on on android home launcher )

For Play-store

1. Open your app on [Publish Google Developer URL](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/)  and select your app
2. On the left menu,click Store Presence > Store listing.
3. There you see "High-res icon".
4. Upload New "High-res icon" of size 512*512.
5. Then Simply Save and Apply this change by click on update button.

For More Details [Follow this Link](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/1078870?hl=en)

Comment: As I mentioned above in my question, I had done this and this didn't have any effect for months

Comment: However, you are right! My app is localized for three languages and High-res icon shoud be uploaded for every language (because description icon was localized for 3 languages). Thank you for your time)